# MS Entlib 5: How to solve error message "Processing of the message failed"

Tags: wpf, enterprise-library-5

I'm using Microsoft enterprise library 5.0 to save logs. 
I saved Trace Event Type(Warning and Error) to file using RollingFlatFile ErrorTraceListener, found error message like

"Message: Processing of the message failed. See summary information below for more information. Should this problem persist, stop the service and check the configuration file(s) for possible error(s) in the configuration of the categories and sinks."

Is it default error message from enterprise library?
If so, please advice me, this error is occured from where and how to solve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by having a null string in the list of categories for the LogEntry. Something like this should work:

```
LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry {
    Message = "This is a message"
};
logEntry.Categories.Add("General");

Logger.Write(logEntry);
```